# Recognition of an operator in a php if statement

Tags: php

I need my code to spot two conditions on is if the url ends in 'easy' and the other if the url ends in a question mark.  My if statement looks like this:

```
if (in_array(basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]), array("easy","?"))) { . . . }
```

This catches 'easy' but not '?'.  How can I get it to spot the question mark as well?

Comment: Logical AND the two conditions if both must apply: `if (in_array(basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]), array("easy")) && in_array(basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]), array("?"))) { . . . }` Use Logical OR instead if one or the other.. though in_array_isn't the best choice of expression

Comment: `url ends in 'easy' and the other if the url ends in a question mark` That is contradictory. Either it can end at `easy` OR it can end at `?`

Comment: I'd question why this would make a difference in the first place...!? If you have query parameters, inspect `$_GET`; otherwise some routing should have taken care of handling `easy` correctly, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the url ends in 'easy' [or] in a question mark

The most concise way to express that is with a [regular expression](http://regular-expressions.info):

```
if (preg_match('/(easy|\\?)$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
```

Comment: And also the most beautiful :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.  My original statement was not the problem.  I found an error elsewhere in the code.  But of the solutions suggested, I like the pregmatch alternative.  So I am giving it a thumbs up.  But I am sticking to array solution because it